# Is it possible to select files in dolphin from the intergrated terminal?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, dolphin

if you have shown the terminal inside of dolphin file manager you can navigate your file-system with cd and the graphical view will change accordingly.

same the other way round - if you navigate to another directory in the graphical part the terminal also changes to the new location.

If i select or deselect files in the graphical part there are no actions in the terminal. 
Is it possible to change the selection in the graphical part with commands from the terminal?

this would make it easy for example to use wildcard to select specific files fast.

this only makes sens if it would also be possible to work with the selected files from the terminal (something like `$ rm $selection` (that would remove all files that are currently selected)

hope someon has ideas how to do this - iam also open for different ideas how to combine command and graphical ways.

Comment: i found that its possible to do things like i asked for in [double commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/) with the internal command line and the [internal commands](http://doublecmd.github.io/doc/en/cmds.html#catmark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with the selected files in the terminal, you can drag and drop them to the terminal. The absolute paths of all selected files will then be inserted at the current cursor position in the termninal.

By the way, this is just a Konsole feature, i.e. you can also drag and drop files to a full-fledged Konsole window outside of Dolphin to achieve the same effect.

I don't know of a way to select files in Dolphin based on commands/wildcards from the terminal.

Comment: i think your answer *that it is not possible* in direct way if the correct one...
the drag & drop operation is a work-around - but does not really fit the *intentional* use mainly the keyboard idea......